# Why does setting the values of a PETSc solution Vector not affect the result of DMDAVecGetArray?

Tags: c++, petsc

The following program is meant to set the value of the internally defined vector in petsc, which can then be read by `DMDAVecGetArray`:

```
#include <petscdmda.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    PetscInitialize(&argc, &argv, (char*)0, NULL);

    DM da;
    Vec vec;
    PetscScalar *array1, *array2;

    DMDACreate3d(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, DM_BOUNDARY_NONE, DM_BOUNDARY_NONE, DM_BOUNDARY_NONE, DMDA_STENCIL_BOX,
                 2, 2, 2, // grid dimensions
                 1, 1, PETSC_DECIDE, // number of dof, stencil width, number of processors in each dimension
                 9, 0, // stencil type, boundary type
                 NULL, NULL, NULL, // number of nodes in each dimension on each processor
                 &da);

    DMSetFromOptions(da);
    DMSetUp(da);
    DMCreateGlobalVector(da, &vec);

    DMDAVecGetArray(da, vec, &array1);
    array1[0] = 12345;
    // returns 12345:
    std::cout << "First value after setting: " << array1[0] << std::endl;
    DMDAVecRestoreArray(da, vec, &array1);

    DMDAVecGetArray(da, vec, &array2);
    // should also return 12345, but returns 4.63557e-310:
    std::cout << "First value after restoring and getting again: " << array2[0] << std::endl;
    DMDAVecRestoreArray(da, vec, &array2);

    VecDestroy(&vec);
    DMDestroy(&da);
    PetscFinalize();

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason the values that are being defining are not being adopted once the array is restored.
The file can be compiled with

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -I$PETSC_DIR/include -I$PETSC_DIR/$PETSC_ARCH/include -L$PETSC_DIR/$PETSC_ARCH/lib -lpetsc
```

Why are the defined values not being adopted after calling `DMDAVecRestoreArray`? How does this script need to be changed in order for `DMDAVecGetArray` to return the defined value?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `VecSetValues`:

```
DM da;
Vec vec;
DMSetFromOptions(da);
DMSetUp(da);
DMCreateGlobalVector(da, vec);

Eigen::Tensor<PetscScalar, 4> F_(9, 2, 1, 1);
F_.setValues({
  {{{0}},  {{1}}}, {{{2}},  {{3}}}, {{{4}},  {{5}}},
  {{{6}},  {{7}}}, {{{8}},  {{9}}}, {{{10}}, {{11}}},
  {{{12}}, {{13}}}, {{{14}}, {{15}}}, {{{16}}, {{17}}},
});
int ni = 9 * 2 * 1 * 1;
std::vector<int> ix(ni);
std::iota(ix.begin()+1, ix.end(), 1);
VecSetValues(vec, ni, ix.data(), F_.data(), INSERT_VALUES);
VecAssemblyBegin(vec);
VecAssemblyEnd(vec);
```